# Calling Method to Print (Arrays and Loops)

Tags: java, arrays, driver, permutation

```
public class Encryption {
private static final int[] encrypt = {2, 9, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 0};
private static final int[] decrypt = new int[8];
private static final int minLength = 10;

String encrypt (String password)    {
    if(password.length()<minLength) {
        return password;

    }   else {
        char[] passArray = password.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.length; i++)    {
            passArray[i] = (char) (passArray[i]);
            }
            return String.valueOf(passArray);
    }
}

String decrypt (String password)    {
    if (password.length()<minLength)    {
        return password;

    }   else {
        char[] arrayDecrypted = password.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayDecrypted.length; i++) {
            arrayDecrypted[i] = (char) (arrayDecrypted[i]);
        }
        return String.valueOf(arrayDecrypted);
    }
}
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import csci130.*;

public class Driver {
public static void main(String args[]){

Encryption pass = new Encryption();

System.out.println("Please enter a password");
String name = KeyboardReader.readLine();

System.out.println("Encrypted Password:  " + pass.encrypt(name));
System.out.println("Decrypted Password:  " + pass.decrypt(name));

  }
}
```

When I try calling my method Encrypt and Decrypt and have the user type in a password it compiles, but only prints out what I typed in.  Its suppose to permutate the password entered changing the index, and than change it back when decrypted.  Above are two different classes Encryption & Driver.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What password are you inputting?  Any input less than 10 characters will returned unchanges from encrypt

Comment: Even when I put something larger than 10 characters its still unchanged.

Comment: Any password longer than 10 characters.

Comment: The permutation is not implemented. The reason you have same result always is the ` passArray[i] = (char) (passArray[i]);` this line take char from position `i` and put it to the position `i`. I this please you should use sole logic that will per-mutate. for this you could use the encrypt array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you password is shorter than 10 your `encrypt()` returns it as is.

Otherwise it is iterating over characters of your password and does the following:

`passArray[i] = (char) (passArray[i]);`

I think it is obvious that this line has not effect.

Comment: Same goes for decryption. Essentially whole code has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

In your encrypt method, why do you do this?

```
passArray[i] = (char) (passArray[i]);
```

What is your intention? (hint.. hint..)

Comment: I'm taking I don't need it :b

Comment: Try `passArray[i] = (char) (passArray[pasArray.length() - i]);` and see what happens.. then try to decrypt that..